# Jquery Multipage not Working properly

Tags: jquery-mobile

```
<div data-role="page" id="mainz">
    <div data-role="header" class="logo">

    </div>


    <div data-role="content">
        <a   id="cv"  data-ajax="false" href="#mainxyz" rel="external" >Sync to System</a>
    </div>



    <div data-role="footer" >
    </div>
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="mainxyz">
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa


</div>
```

I have a multipage : multipage.html The multipage functionality works fine when you browse the file directly. But if you have a page like: home.html and it has a link to multipage.html the multipage functionality of multipage.html doesnt work. If you refresh the page, it will work again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery Mobile have two page templates:

1. Multi page
2. Multi HTML

Multi page has several **`data-role="page"`** divs and multi HTML is of course several **HTML** files.
You can't fully combine them. Only initial **HTML** can have multi page template, every other **HTML** page must have only one **`data-role="page"`** <div>. This is simply how jQuery Mobile works.

Read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/multipage-template-vs-multi-html-template-in-jquery-mobile/)**.